# python list.append messes up decimal places of numbers

Tags: python, list

I am taking in the values from a manifest.json file, the ranges of a variable as `(4, 4.4, 0.1)`. This has 5 values now.
In my code, I am trying to append these 5 values into a list but when I print the list, the decimal places are a little messed up

```
    def frange(start, end, step):
        tmp = start
        while(tmp <= end):
            yield tmp
            tmp += step


    core_er_val = make_tuple(config_vars['core_er_val'])
    core_er = (core_er_val[0], core_er_val[1])

    for i in frange(core_er_val[0], core_er_val[1], core_er_val[2]):
        print i
        core_er_list.append(i)
    print core_er_list
```

So now if i print i, I get:

`4
4.1
4.2
4.3
4.4`

But when I print core_er_list, I end up getting:

```
[4, 4.1, 4.199999999999999, 4.299999999999999, 4.399999999999999]
```

Is there someway I can fix this as later on when I try to compare the value with the index:

```
indexval = core_er_list.index(core_er)
```

I get an error saying that the element is not found.

Comment: You could consider using the `decimal` module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)

Comment: The representation of a list is different to the representation of a single float.

Comment: Compare `str([4.199999999999999])` and `str(4.199999999999999)`